# Access content type with Theme Inspector

Tags: plone, diazo, plone-4.x

I have a question regarding diazo theming in my plone's website.

I have 2 content types in my homepage, "Events" and "News Items". 
I can filter Events in the theme inspector by looking at the HTML code (div class="vevent") but News Items have no class. In fact, none of my own-created content types have a class.

How can I 'register' a class for my content types? This would allow me to manipulate my theme with diazo rules.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the unskinned Plone you'll see that the body class contains some very useful CSS classes:

- template-`current_view`
- portaltype-`current_portal_type`
- section-`1rs_level_subsection`

I think you can find what you need using aboves.

I suggest you to preserve those classes in the skinned theme too. They can be useful.

Comment: Thank you keul but that is not enough for my purposes. I think I didn't explain fully what I wanted.
I have 2 content types in homepage (_Event Items_ & _News Items_). I need to access **BOTH**, **SEPARATELY**. For _Event Items_, Theme Inspector already defines a class ("vevent"), which allows me to filter _Event Items_. For _News Items_ (or any other items, I miss an identifier).

Comment: So probably you must enhance your question by describing where/how those two content types are listed in your home page. I mean: you are talking of a navigation portlet? You are using a default listing view? An home page add-ons products?

Comment: You are right. I got it working but I should have enhanced my question with further details.
I basically found patterns in the Diazo theme HTML and manipulated it with Javascript (jquery).
Thanks a lot for your time, keul. :)